# Execute the query against all databases

Tags: sql-server

I want to execute the below query against all databases.

```
DECLARE @DB_NAME VARCHAR(30)
SET @DB_NAME = 'Employee';

WITH D
AS
(
SELECT @DB_NAME AS DB_NAME, T.NAME AS TABLE_NAME, C.NAME AS COLUMN_NAME
FROM SYS.tables T
INNER JOIN SYS.columns C 
ON T.object_id = C.object_id
WHERE C.name LIKE '%AFFINITY%'
or c.name = 'affinity'
)
SELECT DB_NAME, TABLE_NAME, MAX(COLUMN_NAME) AS COLUMN_NAME FROM D
GROUP BY DB_NAME, TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME`
```

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: What if you replace `SELECT @DB_NAME AS DB_NAME` with `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS DB_NAME`, and get rid of the variable altogether?

Answer (score 0):

There is the undocumented

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

(A `?` in the command will be replaced by the DB name.)

Otherwise you'll need `sp_executesql` and a cursor over `sys.databases`.

The latter is supported, `sp_MSforeachdb` isn't, so for any kind of production system the cursor is the better option (even if a little more work initially). And of course your own query on `sys.databases` can filter the database list.

Answer (score 0):

USE CAREFULLY:

I assume you have a `MYTABLE` in each required database, otherwise this wont work.

```
DECLARE @MYDATABASES NVARCHAR(50)

CREATE TABLE #MYBASE(DB NVARCHAR(50))

DECLARE dbcur CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases s 
WHERE name not in ('master', 'tempdb', 'msdb') --use this to select all databases but system
--WHERE NAME IN ('myfirstDB', 'mysecondDB', 'mythirdDB') --use this to select only certain databases
OPEN dbcur 
FETCH dbcur INTO @MYDATABASES
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
/* MY STATEMENT */

DECLARE @SQLSTATEMENT NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQLSTATEMENT = N'
SELECT  @DB --EDIT WITH YOUR COLUMNS
FROM '+@MYDATABASES+'.dbo.MYTABLE --EDIT THIS
'
INSERT INTO #MYBASE
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLSTATEMENT, N'@DB NVARCHAR(50)', @DB = @MYDATABASES

/* END STATEMENT */
FETCH NEXT FROM dbcur INTO @MYDATABASES
END
CLOSE dbcur
DEALLOCATE dbcur
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #MYBASE
ORDER BY DB
DROP TABLE #MYBASE
```